# Is there a per-application volume control indicator?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, indicator, pulseaudio, volume-control

There was [per-application volume control applet for Gnome 2](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/pulseaudio-mixer-applet-lets-you-change.html).
There is a [per-app volume control extension for Gnome-Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/212/advanced-volume-mixer/).

Is there any indicator applet for Unity like this two?

Comment: From the `sound settings` > `application` tab you can control volume per-app basis. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't know any applet for Unity but you can do this via pavucontrol, which is a separate application!

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years to respond to comments. The Ubuntu version at the time is now EOL and OP has abandoned the question. VTC as `not reproducible`.